# SQL Server RESTORE VERIFY ONLY checks out but cannot RESTORE from backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, restore

This is a real Hail Mary question because I am at a total loss.  Using SQL Server 2017 Developer on Windows 10 x64. I have a backup file and run this command:

```
restore verifyonly from disk = 'f:\temp\northwind.bak';
```

It checks out as as a valid backup.  But then I run this command:

```
restore database [northwind] from disk = 'f:\temp\northwind.bak' with replace;
```

It progresses to 100%, but just before completing I get this error message and the database goes into `Recovery Pending`:

> Processed 348840 pages for database 'northwind', file 'Northwind' on
> file 1. Processed 3 pages for database 'northwind', file
> 'Northwind_log' on file 1.
>
> Msg 3167, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
> RESTORE could not start database 'northwind'.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>
> Msg 5243, Level 22, State 8, Line 12
> An inconsistency was detected during an internal operation.

How can the restore fail if it is supposedly a valid backup file? Any ideas what to look at?

Comment: Only 3 pages? The volume holding the Northwind_log file looks like it might be full.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you mean the disk volume?  There is plenty of space there.

Comment: Whatever block device it is, yes. Error 5243 suggest it might also be a hardware-related failure on the volume(s) you're restoring to, ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-5243-database-engine-error

Comment: Northwind, like pubs, is SO outdated - you would be better off using World Wide Importers or AdventureWorks as sample databases.

Answer (score 0):

In general database Recovery Pending means the database has encountered an internal error (i.e. lock/resources/physical files/transaction logs) which prevents it from bringing it online but not necessarily means it's impossible.

Could be that it couldn't unlock the physical files, could be a symptom of something else.
You can try turning it to online, and see if you get a better error message.

```
ALTER DATABASE [northwind] SET ONLINE
```

Or you can toggle emergency mode and run diagnostics through DBCC CHECKDB i.e.

```
ALTER DATABASE [northwind] SET EMERGENCY
GO
ALTER DATABASE [northwind] SET SINGLE_USER
GO
DBCC CHECKDB ([northwind]) WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS --Optionally run it like such DBCC CHECKDB ([northwind], REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
GO
```

Further information:

- [Toggle DB State](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options)
- [Recovery Pending](https://mstechtalk.com/fix-recovery-pending-state-sql-server/)
- [DBCC CheckDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I cannot perform any of those commands when the database is in recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just run over http://www.edwinmsarmiento.com/the-scariest-lie-we-believed-about-backup-verification/

Could it be possible, that you made your backup without the `CHECKSUM` option? In this cases a `RESTORE VERIFYONLY` would not found page errors.